# Not able to update database datetime null column value with datepicker null value in c#

Tags: c#, datepicker, null

I am updating `DataTime?` column value to `null` in the database using the Stored procedure and able to update `null` value in SQL using the same stored procedure. I am using the below code in C#:

```
if(string.isnullorempty(name))
{
    name= null;
}
    
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd = new SqlCommand("procsavedata", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Created", (datePicker1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) ? (DateTime?)null : datePicker1.Value.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", name);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
catch 
{
}
```

I am able to update the value if `datepicker1` and `name` values exist but if `datepicker` or `name` value is `null` then it is not updating the value in database.

Comment: Empty `catch` block can hide errors thrown in the `try` block. Try to handle and log exception in the `catch` block. May be it will give you the reason of the problem.

Comment: `(object)DBNull.Value`, not `(DateTime?)null`.

Comment: Yes, I am using a catch block with an error message.

Comment: My guess is that the exception mentions that you forgot to provide @Created? That is because you passed `null`.

Comment: @mjwills. Thanks, it is working fine now, accepting null values in database.